# How to combine url with filename from file

Tags: bash

Text file (filename: listing.txt) with names of files as its contents:

```
ace.pdf
123.pdf
hello.pdf
```

Wanted to download these files from url  http://www.myurl.com/

In bash, tried to merged these together and download the files using wget eg:

```
http://www.myurl.com/ace.pdf
http://www.myurl.com/123.pdf
http://www.myurl.com/hello.pdf
```

Tried variations of the following but without success:

```
for i in $(cat listing.txt); do wget http://www.myurl.com/$i; done
```

Comment: Make the first command in your script `set -x`, that'll show you how all your variables are being interpreted.  Do the `wget` commands still look correct?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No need to use `cat` and loop. You can use `xargs` for this:

```
xargs -I {} wget http://www.myurl.com/{} < listing.txt
```

Comment: @ anubhava, this works but I do not quite understand the construct. will be good if you can elaborate a little on the xargs {}

Comment: `-I` option in `xargs` executes given command for each input line using whatever placeholder we use in front of `-I`. We could also use `xargs -I % wget http://www.myurl.com/% < listing.txt` for example. Please also check `man xargs`

Answer (score 1):

Actually, `wget` has options which can avoid loops & external programs completely.

```
   -i file
   --input-file=file
       Read URLs from a local or external file.  If - is specified as file, URLs are read from the standard input.  (Use ./- to read from a file literally named -.)

       If this function is used, no URLs need be present on the command line.  If there are URLs both on the command line and in an input file, those on the command lines will be the first ones to be retrieved.  If --force-html
       is not specified, then file should consist of a series of URLs, one per line.

       However, if you specify --force-html, the document will be regarded as html.  In that case you may have problems with relative links, which you can solve either by adding "<base href="url">" to the documents or by
       specifying --base=url on the command line.

       If the file is an external one, the document will be automatically treated as html if the Content-Type matches text/html.  Furthermore, the file's location will be implicitly used as base href if none was specified.

   -B URL
   --base=URL
       Resolves relative links using URL as the point of reference, when reading links from an HTML file specified via the -i/--input-file option (together with --force-html, or when the input file was fetched remotely from a
       server describing it as HTML). This is equivalent to the presence of a "BASE" tag in the HTML input file, with URL as the value for the "href" attribute.

       For instance, if you specify http://foo/bar/a.html for URL, and Wget reads ../baz/b.html from the input file, it would be resolved to http://foo/baz/b.html.
```

Thus,

```
$ cat listing.txt
ace.pdf
123.pdf
hello.pdf

$ wget -B http://www.myurl.com/ -i listing.txt
```

This will download all the 3 files.